# AWS cli secrets manager add key-value

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I have a secret in AWS Secrets Manager created and have many Key-Value pairs added.
What I need is, to just append one more key-value pair in it using AWS CLI. I cannot find a command for that in documentation (or maybe overlooking something)

I tried this:

```
aws secretsmanager put-secret-value \
--secret-id $SECRET_NAME \
--region $REGION \
--secret-string '{"NEW_KEY":"NEW_VALUE"}'
```

But it removes all old key-value pairs from SecretsManager and leaves the only new one in it.

Comment: As mentioned in the [api](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/apireference/API_PutSecretValue.html) documentation, the secret-string is an arbitrary string that is only recommended to be JSON.  There's API to decode it as a JSON object and modify it.

Comment: @AnonCoward thank you! I understand put-secret-value may not help. Is there any other way/command(s) instead of rewriting old key-values in put-secret-value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS CLI doesn't have that capability as of now. We need to use any external library/service to achieve this.

Below is an example using `jq`.

*Assume if your current secret value is `{"key1": "value1"}`

```
CURR_VAL=$(aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id $SECRET_NAME | jq -r ".SecretString")
# o/p: {"key1": "value1"}

NEW_VAL=$(echo $CURR_VAL | jq -c '. += {"key1": "value2"}')
# This will add or update the value of "key1"
# o/p: {"key1":"value2"}

aws secretsmanager put-secret-value --secret-id $SECRET_NAME --secret-string $NEW_VAL
```

This will update the secret value to `{"key1": "value2"}`

Comment: Without jq, you can also use awscli's `--query` : `aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id $SECRET_NAME --query SecretString --output text`